# The error message TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python-3.x

```
factor = int(input("Which table would you like: "))  
timestable = ([0,0])  
for count in range(1,13):  
    timestable.append([0,0])  
    result = factor * count  
    timestable[count][0] = count  
    timestable [count][1] = result  
for row in timestable:  
    print(row)
```

This is a program that allows a user to enter in a times table and prints out 1 * the number to 12 * the number. But whenever I go to run the code, I get this error message:

```
timestable[count][0] = count    
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

Does anyone know what I have to change in my code?

Comment: You initialise timestable to be a 2-element list (the parentheses don't do anything here), then append 2-element list to it each step of the loop. Thus, timestable becomes something like `[0, 0, [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], ...]`. You're either looking for `extend`, or you want to initialise timestable to be `timestable = `[[0, 0]]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments, the problem is that the line `timestable = ([0,0])` initializes `timestable` as just `[0, 0]`. Thus, after your first `append`, `timestable` looks like this: `[0, 0, [0, 0]]` instead of `[[0, 0], [0, 0]]`, and the value behind `timestable[count]` is not the newly appended `[0,0]` but just the second `0` from initialization.

Maybe you wanted to create a one-tuple holding a list, but then you'd have to use `([0,0],)` (note the trailing comma), but this won't do you any good, either, as you can not append to tuples. Instead, you should initialize it as a nested list. Also, you can shorten the body of the loop by not first appending zeros and then overwriting those zeros, but appending the correct values directly.

```
timestable = [[0,0]]  
for count in range(1, 13):
    timestable.append([count, factor * count])
```

However, you do not need the separate initialization and loop at all; you an just create `timestable` in a single list comprehension (note that here, the `range` starts from `0`):

```
timestable = [[count, factor * count] for count in range(0, 13)]
```